# How Decode a json String in php

Tags: php, json, curl

This is the Json string

```
{"Header":{},
"Body":
    {"ResponseMsg":
        {"response":
            {"ResponseCode":"0020",
                "ResponseDesc": "user is not accepted!",
                "ConversationID": {},
                "OriginatorConversationID":{},
                "ServiceStatus":"0"
            }
        }
     }
}
```

This is the code I am using to decode this string;

```
   $dec = json_decode($json,true);
   var_dump($result->Header->Body->response->ResponseCode);
```

But I keep on getting the following error

> **Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object in **C:\xampp\htdocs\web\server.php** on line **....**

Please assist to decode this icorrectly formated json string

Comment: The json string is valid. Try `var_dump($result->Body->ResponseMsg->response->ResponseCode);` If you had done a `var_dump($result)` you would have seen your object's structure.

Comment: `json_decode(…, true)` means you'll get an array structure, not an object chain.

Comment: Also test your structure inside json. Because your json string and `$result->Header->Body->response->ResponseCode` has different structure.

Comment: 'var_dump($result) ' generates the json string  ' "{"Header":{},"Body":{"ResponseMsg":{"response":{"ResponseCode":"0020","ResponseDesc":"user is not accepted!","ConversationID":{},"OriginatorConversationID":{},"ServiceStatus":"0"}}}}" ' but  ' var_dump($result->Body->ResponseMsg->response->ResponseCode); ' still generates NULL response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$dec = json_decode('{"Header":{},
"Body":
{"ResponseMsg":
    {"response":
        {"ResponseCode":"0020",
            "ResponseDesc": "user is not accepted!",
            "ConversationID": {},
            "OriginatorConversationID":{},
            "ServiceStatus":"0"
        }
    }
 }
}');

echo $dec->Body->ResponseMsg->response->ResponseCode;

Result: '0020'
```

You do not need to use the Header because it falls under the same level with the body.

Answer (score 1):

Header an Body are at the same level.
Try this instead :

```
var_dump($result["Body"]["response"]["ResponseCode"]);
```